# Отправка данных с NodeJS на сервер

Tags: ajax, node.js, post

Добрый день. Нужно отправить на сервер данные с такой структурой

```
        "type": "xxxxxx",
        "data": "{\"title\" : \"Vasya\"}",
        "company_id": 1
},
    "headers": {
        "accept": "application/json"
    }
}
```

Сейчас пробую делать это так

```
const status = await horseman.post('https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/api/v1/logs?token=xxxxxxxx', {
      type: 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
      data: JSON.stringify(data),
      company_id: id
    })
```

Ошибок нет, но данные на сервер не доходят. 
Посоветуйте, как можно отправлять данные асинхронно(желательно без колбеков)?

Answer (score 0):

Изначально нужно решить где проблема, с отправкой или с приёмом на сервере.
Для этого создайте router на `get /test` и прослушайте. Если данные пришли по этому пути, то где-то в роутах вы попутались. Если не пришли, пробуем обычным **ajax** отправить , по типу `$.getJSON('/test', data => console.log(data));` и так же отправке в ответ что-то с сервера. Если сработало, то проблема где-то при отправке.